# Main method not found in class OInnerDemo

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to execute this code in eclipse.

```
class Outer {
  class Inner {
    int i = 10;
  }
}
class OInnerDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Outer o = new Outer();
    Outer.Inner i = o.new Inner();
    System.out.println(i.i);
  }
}
```

But I am getting an error message :

> Error: Main method not found in class OInnerDemo, please define the
>   main method as:    public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX
>   application class must extend JavaFX.application.Application

But I have executed the same code in cmd and I got the output as 10.
Why is this code not executed in Eclipse?

Comment: Make sure you save the file with name "OInnerDemo.java" and add public modifier to it i.e. public class OInnerDemo

Answer (score 1):

You must make your `OInnerDemo` nested class `static` and then you can start `main` Method in Eclipse.

**`Inner Classes` (a non static nested class) cannot define any static members itself.**

You can read more about the difference [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

> Inner Classes
>
> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated
>   with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that
>   object's methods and fields. Also, because an inner class is
>   associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members
>   itself.